# How should I use factories in Laravel when I have default values in DB

Tags: php, laravel

I have a factory:

```
$factory->define(\App\MissingData::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $operations = Operation::all()->pluck('id')->toArray();
    $operationId = $faker->randomElement($operations);
    $operation = Operation::find($operationId);
    $meters = $operation->meters->pluck('id')->toArray();
    $arrStatus = ['Done', 'Undone'];

    return [
        'operation_id' => $operationId,
        'meter_id' => $faker->randomElement($meters),
        'date_ini' => $faker->dateTimeThisYear,
        'date_end' => $faker->dateTimeThisYear,
        'status' => $faker->randomElement($arrStatus),
    ];
});
```

In my migration, I have:

```
$table->string('status')->default('Undone');
```

When I want to insert an array in DB, I always prefer to use factory:

```
factory(MissingData::class)->create($missingData);
```

with

```php
return [
    'operation_id' => $measure->operation_id,
    'meter_id' => $measure->meter_id,
    'conso_prod' => $measure->conso_prod,
    'date_ini' => $missingDataIni,
    'date_end' => $missingDataEnd,
];
```

The wanted behaviour is to insert the status: 'Undone' configured in DB, but my factory will generate a fake status, so I will always have to send `Undone` status to my factory, which is not the point of using a DB default.

How am I supposed to manage this. Using factory to create and insert model is a good practice.

Using default in DB is also very practical, I believe they can be used both at the same time, but I don't see how should I do that.

Any idea ?

Comment: Your factory defines a value for `status`, will can either override with your own value or set it to `null`

Comment: So I will have to specify the value of this field each insert, I will not be able to omit it, will I ? Isn't it the idea when defining default ? not having to specify them ?

Comment: You can also remove from your factory.

Comment: yes, but if I do so, I will never be able to seed dummy data for those 2 fields.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to default the status to `undone` then have a seperate state for `done` and any other status' that you may add.

```
$factory->define(\App\MissingData::class, function (Faker $faker) {
   $operations = Operation::all()->pluck('id')->toArray();
   $operationId = $faker->randomElement($operations);
   $operation = Operation::find($operationId);
   $meters = $operation->meters->pluck('id')->toArray();

   return [
       'operation_id' => $operationId,
       'meter_id' => $faker->randomElement($meters),
       'date_ini' => $faker->dateTimeThisYear,
       'date_end' => $faker->dateTimeThisYear,
       'status' => 'Undone',
   ];
```

});

```
$factory->state(\App\MissingData::class, 'done', fn() => ['status' => 'Done']);
```

Then when you want the status to be done you would use the state like this.

```
factory(\App\MissingData)->state('done')->create();
```

Comment: Also as a side note you may want to cache the results from the queries that your executing in this factory so it doesn't slow you down when using it in tests. It would also be a good idea to just create the related models right in the factory then override them when you need to.